# .net VSTO save excel file and share on a server

Tags: .net, excel, deployment, vsto

I have a requirement at job to produce an Excel file and then to put it on a shared folder so managers can take a copy and consult it.

I have been using VSTO to develop a part on my application.

When I execute this application, the excel file pops up and everything is populated properly.

If I save a local copy of the document on my desktop and I open it again, I receive error saying VSTO could not be downloaded.

Is there a way to:

1.execute the application
2. save a local copy on my desktop
3. use this file as a normal excel file

from an Excel Workbook application in visual studio 2010.

Please ask any question if I am not clear, it's the first time I use VSTO and some of it is still unclear to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.

Here's where I found it:
http://gluegood.blogspot.com/2010/07/namecode-classc-sharp.html

Simply Add "RemoveCustomization" at the end of the startup method.

```
private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        [ code removed for clarity ]

        this.RemoveCustomization();
    }
```

This removes every customizations you made on your application.
This allows you to execute your application, save a local copy on your desktop, and open without the need to install or deploy anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I Believe you should document yourself better about VSTO deployment issues.

There were somne changes between version 2007 and version 2010 to help and simplify deployment with ClickOnce, check on MSDN.

Comment: That is the thing, I don't want to deploy an application on the client. I want to produce an excel file and then share it to people.
The thing is, we need to modify the application at each time it is executed because many settings will changes. It has  been discussed to use manual configuration to let the users set their own configuration, but this was rejected. So I need to produce the excel file, and give it to managers.

Comment: Yes but since the excel file you are going to build will reference some code located in the external assemblies you will build, you should deploy all together, you can't simply use it as a normal excel file.